# Pruning Subsets

Tags: linear-algebra

Very confused with this pruning malarky any help appreciated thanks:

Consider the following subset of $\mathcal{P}_3(\Bbb{R})$: $Z:=\{f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4,f_5\}$ with 
$f_1(x)=1+2x+3x^2-4x^3$, $f_2(x)=1+2x-x^2-2x^3$, $f_3(x)=1+2x+11x^2-8x^3$, $f_4(x)=1-x-2x^2+2x^3$ and $f_5(x)=1-x+2x^2$

Prune $Z$ to produce a linearly independent subset $Y$ with Span($Z$) = Span($Y$)

What is the dimension of Span($Z$)?

Is $p_1$ an element of Span($Z$)?

Extend $Y$ to give a basis for $\mathcal{P}_2(\Bbb{R})$.

Comment: What is $\mathcal{P}_2(\Bbb{R})$?

Comment: It's Z, which is the set of the functions 1-5

Comment: Z is a **subset** of $\mathcal{P}_2(\Bbb{R})$ so $\mathcal{P}_2(\Bbb{R})$ must be some bigger set. How is $\mathcal{P}_2(\Bbb{R})$ defined? What I mean is, what is inside $\mathcal{P}_2(\Bbb{R})$

Comment: Ah sorry it's "real polynomial functions of degree at most 3" (I had written 2 by accident) $\mathcal{P}_3(\Bbb{R})$

Comment: are you familiar with the method of gaussian elimination on matrices?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is to find an independent subset of $f_1, f_2, f_3, f_4, f_5$. That means finding a set of $i$ values such as that if the expression $\sum_i a_i f_i(x)=0$ for any $x$ has the unique solution $a_i=0$. If there is any other solution, the polynomials are not independent.

$f_1$ is independent on it's own

For $f_1, f_2$ we have $a_1 f_1(x)+a_2 f_2(x)=0$ or $(a_1+a_2)+(2a_1+2a_2)x+(3a_1-a_2)x^2+(-4a_1-2a_2)x^3=0$. This is true for all real $x values only if

$$
a_1+a_2=0\\
2a_1+2a_2=0\\
3a_1-a_2=0\\
-4a_1-2a_2=0
$$ 
The only solution is $a_1=a_2=0$ so $f_1,f_2$ are independent

We follow the same procedure for $f_1,f_2,f_3$. We get:

$$
a_1+a_2+a_3=0\\
2a_1+2a_2+2a_3=0\\
3a_1-a_2+11a_3=0\\
-4a_1-2a_2-8a_3=0
$$
If we add equations 1 and 3 we get $4a_1+12a_3=0$ or $a_1=-3a_3$.
If we use this in the first equation, we get $a_2=2a_3$. If we plug in these values in all equations, we obtain zeros. For example $a_3=1, a_1=-3, a_2=2$ is a solution of the system of equations. Therefore $f_1,f_2, f_3$ are not independent, and we could "prune" $f_3$.
You need to continue for $f_4$ and $f_5$.